# Can we use multiple click_action in firebase api fcm notifications?

Tags: firebase, api, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

How we can use multiple **click_action** in firebase API fcm notifications?
for example:

```
{
  "notification": {
        "title" : "title",
        "body"  : "body text",
        "icon"  : "ic_notification",
        **"click_action" : "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1",
        "click_action_2" : "OPEN_ACTIVITY_2"**
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), there is only a single `click_action` parameter per message. If you want the user to take a follow-up action, you'll have to implement inside the code that handles their initial click.

This sounds a bit like a ;[XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though.

Comment: Sir, do you mean that I have to implement on the android side (Using Broadcast Reciever)?